# Customize filename in webpack

Tags: webpack

I am using webpack extensively and my config looks something like this —

```
{
    entry: {
        main: './d11-web/lib/bootstrap.ts',
        sw: './d11-web/sw/sw-bootstrap.ts',
        kill: './d11-web/sw/sw-kill-switch.ts'
      },
      output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'public'),
        filename: '[name]-[chunkhash].js'
      },
}
```

The problem is that I want `sw` and `kill` files to not have the `[chunkhash]` appended to their name, where as for `main` I do want the `[chunkhash]`.

Is there a direct way to achieve this or via some plugin? If its a plugin what property should be updated on what event so that the file names are as per me.

Comment: you can use this library https://www.npmjs.com/package/rename-output-webpack-plugin